# Prevent mixing training examples from different TFRecords files

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

I'm training a model on video frame sequences. I have videos stored as tfrecords files, (each video is a separate tfrecords file), with each frame encoded as a single tf.train.Example. During training I read batches of frames and run them through the model. However, I see that it is possible for frames from different videos to end up in the same batch. For the model I'm training it doesn't make sense and is actually harming performance. Is there a way to make sure that a batch of frames contains frames only from the same video?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `tf.data.Dataset.filter` method. The predicate compares video ids of the first and last frames. If they're different, then the whole batch is dropped:

```
def ensure_same_video_in_batch(video_ids, *args):
    first_frame_video_id, last_frame_video_id = video_ids[0], video_ids[-1]
    return tf.equal(first_frame_video_id, last_frame_video_id)


dataset = dataset.filter(ensure_same_video_in_batch)
```